# How can I change the color/icon of folders in windows using java program?

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, operating-system, java-native-interface

I am working on a project that needs notify user when a change is made in a folder by changing its color or icon.
I can do this manually by editing registry in windows but I want to do this with the help of java program.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) API

> The WatchService API is fairly low level, allowing you to customize it. You can use it as is, or you can choose to create a high-level API on top of this mechanism so that it is suited to your particular needs.

[Oracle blog on the same](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes)